# TensorFlow fails to use gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I'm getting started with TensorFlow, but I cannot make it use GPU instead of CPU with TensorFlow 1.2.1.

I've got a laptop equipped with a NVIDIA GTX 850M which is CUDA 5.0 compatibility.

The CUDA Toolkit is installed with the latest version available.

cuDNN is installed with the latest version available.

I've set up the environment variables just as is shown here : https://nitishmutha.github.io/tensorflow/2017/01/22/TensorFlow-with-gpu-for-windows.html

If I install the latest version of TensorFlow via pip: "pip install tensorflow-gpu" in the cmd prompt, then TensorFlow does not recognize my GPU and acts like I've got none: 'Device mapping: no known device'.

If instead I install tensorflow via 'pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl' then everything works fine.

Has anyone an idea why the latest version of TF does that?

Comment: How do you know it's not using the GPU?

Comment: When I force it with "with tf.device("/gpu:0"):" , it tells me no such device is found. If I do the same with the CPU, everything works fine. Additionally, the log_device_placement log confirms that it uses cpu:0.

Comment: Maybe there was another tensorflow (a non-gpu one) sitting on a prioritized path? In my case it was a previously run 'python setup.py install --user'  that apparently messed things up

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Tensorflow, you can check the GPU availability as

```
gpu_available = tf.test.is_gpu_available()
is_cuda_gpu_available = tf.test.is_gpu_available(cuda_only=True)
is_cuda_gpu_min_3 = tf.test.is_gpu_available(True, (3,0))
```

`tf.test.is_gpu_available` will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` instead